# Trouble Adding New Logo

Tags: logo

I'm trying to replace an old logo on a site with a new one.

- The old logo was 222×120px
- and the new one is 222×150px.

I uploaded the new one and had it overwrite the old one. My site hasn't changed though. The 30px added to the new logo is the only difference between the two and it just says "Productions". There should be room for at least part of the "Productions" part to show, but it looks exactly like the old one.

How can I fix this? I'm supposed to have this site finished today and this is the last thing stopping me from being done.

The logo I'm talking about is the one in the top-left corner [of this site](http://www.millermusicproductions.com/).

Thanks

Comment: I understand the urgency of your problem, but this is *not* a WordPress question. It's a CSS issue. Your stylesheet is locking the size of the image and expecting a 222x120px graphic. Just replacing the graphic is not enough - see Chris Cox's answer below for a full fix. At the same time, I'm closing this as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 429 (or thereabouts) of your theme's style.css, change height: 120px to height: 150px.